# Short description can not be edited by Magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, import, magmi

Through Magmi I made a mass import.

I did a test by adding to the field **short_description** the value 'test test test'
Then I added the correct values with a second import.
But this happens

From here it's all ok:

[image]

Whether within the product this:

[image]

The problem is about 5000 products

I noticed that the change only takes effect if, within the product, I change something in the short description (for example I write 'test test test test'), save and I start the Magmi, so the new import works

How can I fix it?

I've already done reindex and clear cache, but nothing

Answer (score 0):

**In my case it started working after I did `show create table catalog_product_entity_text`:) go figure**

I will describe the general steps you can take to identify the problem.

Here is how to debug it:

1. open up `magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php` and add some debugging code after line 1097:

   ```
   1097                 $sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=VALUES(`value`)";
   1098                 /*HACK*/
   1099                 if($cpet == 'catalog_product_entity_text'){
   1100                 $this->log($sql,"warning");
   1101                 $this->log(print_r($data,true),"warning");
   1102                 }
   ```

   Now when you run magmi you should get warnings like these:
   [image]
   Now you know what SQL command is executed to update `short_description` and with what parameters.
2. Find `attribute_id` of `short_description` (in my case it is 73):

   ```
   select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='short_description' and entity_type_id=(SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code='catalog_product');
   ```
3. See in warnings if you can find `Array` with `[1] => 73`. If not open up `magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php` and debug your way up to an error.
4. If you can find `[1] => 73` connect to Mysql and issue that SQL update query:

   ```
   INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity_text
   (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, 
   `value`)
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   `value`=VALUES(`value`)
   ```

In place of `?` enter:

- entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code='catalog_product'
- attribute_id - see #2
- store_id - your store_id, in my case it is 0
- entity_id = your product id
- value - your short description

If that sql query doesn't update your data double check your table structure and MySQL database configuration.

Report back what you find out.